# Loading/use CsvHelper in PowerShell 7/.NET 5

Tags: powershell, csvhelper

Long story short - requesting assistance loading/using CsvHelper in PS 7 w/.NET 5.  Dll loads fine but no exported commands available.  Added a manifest (nested, root, etc) with full export didn't expose.  Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

---

Long story long - Have a system with fairly vanilla installs of pwsh v7.1.3 and .NET v5.0.300.  I've been assigned a project to work with very large CSV files and process them with SQLBULKCOPY.  The files will have formatting challenges as well as date (datetime2) fun so a Csv parser seems to be the best course of action.

After seeing that CsvHelper can cut through the parsing requirements, is compiled for .NET 5 (no dependencies), and reading reviews showing 20%+ better performance than another DLL (lu...) being tested I would like to leverage it for the project.

This solution will be used on systems with no access to the internet and users with limited skills, so the hope is to use just include the CsvHelper dll in the script module directory.

Loading the CsvHelper.dll (net5.0) file `import-module "...\CsvHelper.dll"` appears to work.  Get-Module shows the dll is loaded but doesn't show any exported commands.  Get-Command doesn't either.  I've tried creating a manifest file for the DLL (nestedmodules, rootmodule, etc. and export specific publics, *) but am unsuccessful.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple and would appreciate assistance.  Thanks much.

Comment: CsvHelper is a generic helper library, not a PowerShell module - _there are no commands to be exported_. You'll have to write your own functions or cmdlets take make use of it

Comment: There is of course the [Getting Started](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/) page for CsvHelper. Did you read that?

Answer (score 0):

When I started this project the first test was using a Lumenworks parser.  It can be loaded into PS and used directly.  That was nice and it set my head in that specific direction.  Moving into CsvHelper I was wanting (hoping) to stay in PS only. There were bureaucratic motivations to not to go into studio, compile a dll, and the like.

My hope was to load the helper dll in PS and then inline the C# code.  Something along the lines of:

```
Import-Module "C:\...\CsvHelper.dll"
```

or

```
$Assem = (
   <?? for csvhelper>
)
```

with

```
$source = @"
using CsvHelper;
<C# around using CsvHelper>
"@
```

and appropriate Add-Type

```
Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
```

What I wanted to do can probably be done but I don't have the skills for it.  For now I'm going with a Studio project.  Will build set it to do what I want, use it in PS for the solution and deal with the politics.

Appreciate the inputs.